# How do I reference a Django settings variable in my models.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

This is a very beginner question.  But I'm stumped.  How do I reference a Django settings variable in my model.py?

```
NameError: name 'PRIVATE_DIR' is not defined
```

Also tried a lot of other stuff including `settings.PRIVATE_DIR`

**settings.py:**

```
PRIVATE_DIR = '/home/me/django_projects/myproject/storage_dir'
```

**models.py:**

```
# Problem is here.
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location=PRIVATE_DIR)

class Customer(models.Model): 
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    image = models.ImageField(storage=fs, upload_to='photos', blank=True, null=True)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: `from django.conf import settings` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Answer (score 449, accepted):

Try with this: `from django.conf import settings` then
`settings.VARIABLE` to access that variable.

VARIABLE should be in capital letter. It will not work otherwise.

Comment: Something relevant: if you have several instances of `settings_something.py` due to a project deployed in several environments, do not try to import from `app.settings`. Overwritten variables in the other files won't take effect. Always use the import mentioned in this answer. It took me a few hours to realize what was going on in my project.

Comment: This works, if it is properly configured: with environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or with manage.py command line parameter --settings=.. Read more in docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

Answer (score 133):

```
from django.conf import settings

PRIVATE_DIR = getattr(settings, "PRIVATE_DIR", None)
```

Where it says `None`, you will put a default value incase the variable isn't defined in settings.

Answer (score 5):

There's an example of importing the `EMAIL_HOST_USER` from the *settings.py* file and use it to send an email:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def post_share(request, post_id): 
   # ...
   send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [
                      settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 'ahmnouira@gmail.com'])
```