# How can I set a DateField format in django from the model?

Tags: python, django, format, datefield

I am creating a django application and I have the next problem: this error is shown when I want to set a date:

```
ValidationError [u"'12/06/2012' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

For this model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

    date1 = models.DateField(null=True)
    date2 = models.DateField(null=True)
```

How can I set the DateField format to be `%m/%d/%Y`.

The option `"input_formats"` is not recognized.

Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @bruno as mentioned in his answer, `input_formats` is a forms field, however it can be used to control the date format saved from the model.

In `settings.py` set `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` as below:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']
```

And in your form you could do something like below:

```
class ClientDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
       model = ModelA
```

Comment: This will only work if `USE_L10N` is False. You may also need to set `DATE_FORMAT` used when printing a date in the templates.

Comment: Can't be set from the model. It only applies to the Form.

Comment: Why use settings? Cant it be set in the same forms.py?

Comment: This might look simple, but settings.py seems unreachable from the app's folder. I've tried every possible way of importing settings.py, which is inside the project's folder.

Comment: How are you importing settings?

Comment: @101is5 try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867797/how-do-i-reference-a-django-settings-variable-in-my-models-py

Answer (score 31):

`input_formats` is a [`forms.DateField` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats), not a `model.DateField` option. You have to set it in your form, not in your models.

Comment: To create models I am using generic views. How could I change how the date is formatted from the model?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the LANGUAGE_CODE to get the correct date formate for the local.
`LANGUAGE_CODE ='en-GB'`
Then have `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d']` in the `settings.py` which can be called when needed at anytime.

```
date_birth = forms.DateField(label='Date of birth', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=YEAR_CHOICES, input_formats= DATE_INPUT_FORMATS))
```

Comment: It seems like "input_formats" is no longer a valid kwarg. I've got this error: TypeError: SelectDateWidget.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'

Comment: I think this should be set as the correct answer. And forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y']) is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py, insert:

```
USE_L10N = False

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

- DATE_INPUT_FORMATS's data type must be a list, containing the format as a string.
- %d/%m/%Y is just my format of choice.

As of lately(jan 2022), settings.py does not contain `USE_L10N` by default (neither `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`, but this one is expected not the be there, I guess).
It seems like, although `USE_L10N` isn't there by default, not only it does exists somewhere but it's also set to True, because setting up `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` alone (i.e. without making `USE_L10N` explicitly False) will not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who watch this in 2023!!!
To make this work I just added:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d.%m.%Y"]
USE_L10N = False
```

in my settings.py and it worked. I now can input 20.12.2020 in my form.
My form is auto generated from models.Model class

Comment: Isn't that exactly what @101is5 already answered? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70709867/13138364