# How to parse date string containing mm/yyyy in django models?

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-models

I'm writing existing SQLite3 database to django models. Some dates replicate themselves and I need them encoded, so I create a class in the model to store unique periods in the following form: `mm/yyyy`.

What would be the right syntax to set date, so in django they have the same format, but as a datetime object?

```
class Periods(models.Model):
    period = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.period
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30911955/15042684

Comment: input_formats seems to be an argument for forms.DateField() not models.DateField(), so it throws an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'`
Is there any chance I can use something similar for models.DateField()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.period.strftime('%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the whole date in period field and in your **str** print only the mm/yyyy.

Like this.

```py
def __str__(self): 
    return self.period.strftime('%m/%Y')
```