# django date input format is not interpreted properly

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am trying to setup a Model and a corresponding ModelForm with django containing a DateField/Input.

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myDate = models.DateField()

from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'myDate': forms.DateInput(format=("%d/%m/%Y")) 
        }
```

But sadly, when I enter a date in the form that results out of MyModelForm, the day and the month get exchanged. E.g. 1/2/22 will result in January 2nd 2022 instead of feburary 1st 2022. What else do I need to do, so the date gets interpreted properly?

Comment: You can add myDate as custom formfield by `myDate=forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y']) ` Can you try this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the format only in your widget’s form is just used as a display, you still need to pass it to specify the field `myDate` as a `DateField` in your form:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myDate = models.DateField()

from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myDate = forms.DateField(input_formats=["%d/%m/%Y"])

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'myDate': forms.DateInput(format=("%d/%m/%Y")) 
        }
```

Another option to set this up would be to add the format inside the `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT` variable in `settings.py`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats for more

Comment: Adding your suggestion inside MyModel results in an error: `TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'`

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I was reading from the `model.DateField` docs but it was from `form.DateField`. Edited the answer to account for that

Comment: Also this question might be useful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911612/how-can-i-set-a-datefield-format-in-django-from-the-model